# question about mail replying

Tags: professionalism

I want to ask how can I reply this e-mail;

***It was a pleasure meeting you in person a couple of days ago, hope will have this chance again and happy to be working together with you.***

we are working together but we did not meet until last week when he came to our city. today he sent me this email as a thank for my hospitality and to continue the work. How can I express that it was also my pleasure and and ....ets

Comment: The answer depends so much as to *why* this e-mail was sent to you - please expand your question to add some context.

Comment: we are working together but we did not meet until last week when he came to our city. today he sent me this email as a thank for my hospitality and to continue the work. How can I express that it was also my pleasure and and ....ets.

Comment: It doesn't sound like an email reply is really needed. If it was face to face it's customary to give a reply such as "The pleasure was all mine." or "It was a pleasure meeting you too." or something like that. But for an email message that sounds too short and not obligatory.

Comment: @mimaar Please edit your question rather than putting clarifications in comments.

Answer (score 2):

You could answer it something similar to this:

> Thank you for taking the time to come to *city name*, it was great to
>   have had the opportunity to meet you and to work with you in person.  I am
>   sure that we will continue to work together successfully into the future.

Or something along those lines :)  You want to in effect thank HIM for coming to see you, and reassure him that it was a productive and enjoyable experience :)